# Android how to reset ImageView layout to original after zooming and drag

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, zooming

I need to implement zooming, panning and then reset the ImageView to original scale/location.  I use view.setImageMatrix(matrix) to perform zooming and moving in FrameLayout. Works perfectly so far.  To restore to original layout, I tried to save the original matrix and reset to it,   It doesn't work and I am kinda stuck. Appreciate any suggestions or tips!

The following are my current code:

- a ViewPager contains fragments per Image

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

- The fragment contains ImageView

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/catalogue_test" />
</FrameLayout>
```

- The java code does the zooming and panning work just fine, that actually was original from a tutorial page:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

      ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         Log.d(tag, "ACTION_DOWN");
         isDoubleTap = false;

         savedMatrix.set(matrix);
         start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
         Log.d(tag, "mode=DRAG");
         mode = DRAG;
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
         Log.d(tag, "ACTION_POINTER_UP");
         mode = NONE;
         Log.d(tag, "mode=NONE");
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         Log.d(tag, "ACTION_MOVE");
         if (mode == DRAG) {
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
         } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            double newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(tag, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 10f) {
               matrix.set(savedMatrix);
               float scale = (float) (newDist / oldDist);
               matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
         }

         if(isDoubleTap == false) {
            view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            Log.d(tag, String.format("(%d, %d) - scale(%f, %f) xy(%f, %f)", view.getTop(), view.getLeft(),  view.getScaleX(), view.getScaleY(), view.getX(), view.getY()));
         }

         break;

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
         oldDist = spacing(event);
         Log.d(tag, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
         if (oldDist > 10f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.d(tag, "mode=ZOOM");
         }
         break;
      }

      gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
      return true; // indicate event was handled
   }
```

Comment: Try invalidating your view.

Comment: I tried the following, none seems work: final ViewPager vp=(ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);     
               
             vp.invalidate();
             v.invalidate();

Comment: vp is the viewPager that contains the imageView.  v is the imageView

Comment: @Sean you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any luck with the setImageMatrix(new Matrix()) method, but setting the scale type then resetting it worked.

```
setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); 
setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but here is my answer.

1-)get startedMatrix of imageView onCreate method

2-)and changed ACTION_POINTER and ACTION_POINTER_UP method to these

```
       --- case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted
               mode = NONE;
               break;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:// second finger lifted
               fingerLifted();
               matrix.set(startedMatrix);
               view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
               mode = NONE;
               Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
               break;
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't the original imageView Matrix simply an identity matrix?

`imageView.setImageMatrix(new Matrix());` -- this will be a matrix with no translations/scales/etc aka the default/original matrix

Comment: invalidate isn't going to do what you think it does. It just redraws the view using the same zoomed/panned matrix. What you need is to reset the actual matrix.

Comment: I'm actually a little surprised that this isn't working for me - have you verified that this works? I just tried it, without success.

Comment: I actually hadn't verified it, but I just took the time to do so and it did work. I was keeping a variable `transformMatrix` that contained the matrix for the view and did `transformMatrix = new Matrix()` and then `imageView.setImageMatrix(transformMatrix)` and that worked. As a side note, I did have to say `scrollTo(0,0)` as well because I am also using a `Scroller` object.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my research...
to reset ImageView to original Scale/Position
try this very simple code... just put this

```
setCotentView(R.layout.activity_image);
```

This will reset your ImageView from the start :) and it will work.

Comment: And if you have any other elements present, they all go splat.

Comment: how to resolve it if imageView is dynamically added?